# Is it possible to integrate CRM with SharePoint using a plugin?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have been tasked with creating a CRM 2011 online plugin that connects to a SharePoint online site.  The plugin is to create new document sets after a certain action takes place in CRM.

I know that all plugins must be sand-boxed in CRM 2011 online. I'm not sure if this project is even feasible considering the limitations of the sandbox.  I'm also not 100% sure if it is possible to create document sets using the SharePoint web service.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, then yes. It's possible. When you create a plugin, you code in C# and you can call web services. In fact, tomorrow, I'll be coding a call to an external web service to update some entity's status so I better be right on this one.

Have you created plugins before?

Comment: I have not, but thanks for your input.  Now I just need to figure out how to create document sets using the SharePoint web service.

Comment: @user1913954 That's a SharePoint issue. I'm more of a CRM soul. If you're satisfied with the reply, check it as an answer. Otherwise, please elaborate on what more you need.

Comment: @user1913954: I am looking for the same. Were you able to achieve? If yes, can you please mention the steps here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can use Sharepoint Apis or web service to create document in sharepoint and can use the same in MS CRM plugin.

Refer: http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/crm-2011-integration-with-sharepoint-custom-document-management/